# Fixing pngcrush for compiling libgdx in iOS

Tags: libgdx

I'm trying to compile the hello world example for iOS (generated with gdx-setup-ui). After following the walkthrough for fixing the pngcrush (https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/IOSWIP)  I'm getting the following error in Xamarin Studio: "The pngcrush utility could not be found.."

Any ideas?

Comment: Please add a few more details about what exactly you did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that when creating a "fake" pngcrush file, I had to give the file the right permissions. Following the answers in [How do I make this file.sh executable via double click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8409946/how-do-i-make-this-file-sh-executable-via-double-click) solved the problem.