# how to script folder deletion on MAC

Tags: macos, bash

I believe it should be straight forward but either I am having a bad day or I simply can't find what I am looking for.

Please help.

I need to run following commands in MAC Terminal in order to get rid of following entries:

```
sudo rm -Rf /Applications/Network\ Connect.app
sudo rm -Rf /Library/Frameworks/net.juniper.DSApplicationServices.framework
sudo rm -Rf /Library/Frameworks/net.juniper.DSCoreServices.framework
sudo rm -Rf /Library/Frameworks/net.juniper.DSNetworkDiagnostics.framework
sudo rm -Rf /Library/Internet\ Plug-ins/net.juniper.DSSafariExtensions.plugin
sudo rm -Rf /Library/Widgets/Network\ Connect.wdgt
sudo rm -Rf /usr/local/juniper
sudo rm -Rf /private/var/db/receipts/net.juniper.NetworkConnect.bom
sudo rm -Rf /private/var/db/receipts/net.juniper.NetworkConnect.plist
sudo rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/ncproxyd.plist
```

It does it's job but it's not exactly elegant. I was also thinking about providing this to my colleagues so I wanted to create some sort of .bat file for MAC.

I really spent about half day trying to figure it out but it doesn't work :(

Can somebody help me to create a .sh file or bash file which will do execute the commands above?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make this file.sh executable via double click?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8409946/how-do-i-make-this-file-sh-executable-via-double-click)

Comment: Sounds like you really was to to know about Unix and Bash shell scripting or Ruby or Python or Perl or even AppleScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a script file, let's say it's called deletion.sh and add the lines: -

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -Rf /Applications/Network\ Connect.app
rm -Rf /Library/Frameworks/net.juniper.DSApplicationServices.framework
rm -Rf /Library/Frameworks/net.juniper.DSCoreServices.framework
rm -Rf /Library/Frameworks/net.juniper.DSNetworkDiagnostics.framework
rm -Rf /Library/Internet\ Plug-ins/net.juniper.DSSafariExtensions.plugin
rm -Rf /Library/Widgets/Network\ Connect.wdgt
rm -Rf /usr/local/juniper
rm -Rf /private/var/db/receipts/net.juniper.NetworkConnect.bom
rm -Rf /private/var/db/receipts/net.juniper.NetworkConnect.plist
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/ncproxyd.plist
```

Then, in terminal you need to set the executable flag to the script: -

```
chmod +x deletion.sh
```

Note that the executable flag may be removed when the script is copied to another machine or network drive, so you may have to do that after copying.

Finally, you can call the script with sudo

```
sudo ./deletion.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a batch file, you have one. That list of commands ***is*** your shell script. To execute it, just save hem into a file add the `bash` command to the front of that file's name:

```
$ bash commands_I_want_to_execute.txt
```

If you want to get fancy, you can put a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) on the top and set the *execution bit* using [chmod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod). That will make your script a *real* shell script.

However, in order for your shell script to be found, you need to either prefix it with a path, or put it in a directory that's included in your `PATH`. Here, I'll just prefix it:

```
$ chmod a+x commands_I_want_to_execute.txt  # Suffix doesn't really matter. It's executable
$ ./commands_I_want_to_execute.txt          # Now this will be executed
```

If you are really bothered by the suffix, change it with the `mv` command:

```
$ mv commands_I_want_to_execute.txt commands_I_want_to_execute.sh
```

**NOTE**: If you create a file with Text Edit, create it as a plain text file and not as a RTF file.