# On Mac OSX how can I associate a script file with Terminal so double clicking the icon launches Terminal?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, terminal

I have a python script that I can run in the usual way using Terminal. For example, launch Terminal, cd to the directory, then type ./xxx.py where xxx.py is the name of the file that contains the script.

Now I want to make an icon on the desktop that launches Terminal and runs the python file when I double click it. How do I do that? I thought I could make a shell file with the cd and the launch command and then associate that shell file with Terminal. But I can't seem to associate it with Terminal.

Somebody said to name the shell file with the suffix '.command' but that causes it to launch Flash Builder. I don't know where that associate is set. I can't manually associate Terminal because I can't find it. It isn't in /Applications.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/8409946/754997

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your Desktop you coul create a file with the following content

```
#!/bin/bash

python PATH_TO_YOUR_PYTHON_FILE
```

Then you must make it executable via

```
chmod u+x FILE_ON_DESKTOP
```

Alternatively you can create a symbolic link to your python file and make it executable.

You can find *Terminal* in `/Applications/Utilities`

Comment: To find Applications and files use Spotlight.