# Create a batch file which remove folder in my Desktop - mac

Tags: python, macos, shell, batch-file, terminal

i am a mac user. and i want to remove a folder of my desktop by double clicking any file.
(just like uninstaller).

So, Without using Terminal or manually delete , i want to remove that folder by creating a file. so when i double click on that file, it automatically remove a folder of my desktop.

Comment: randomly remove a single folder or all folders on your desktop?

Comment: remove a single folder at any location, desktop is just an example.

Comment: So that means you can specify a location? is `rm -rf /path/to/your/folder` working for you?

Comment: yes.. but i want to do it by batch file.so when i double click on that file it can works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a specific folder to delete, you can write a `sh` file.

**my-remove.sh:**

```
rm -rf /path/to/your/folder
```

please don't forget to execute `chmod` on it:

```
chmod a+x my-remove.sh
```

Then you can remove `/path/to/your/folder` when you double click `my-remove.sh`

**EDIT:**

I'll sum it here.

1, Open Terminal in mac

2, `cd ~/Desktop`

3, `touch my-remove.sh`

4, `echo "rm -rf /path/to/your/folder" > my-remove.sh`

5, `chmod a+x my-remove.sh`

Then you can see a `my-remove.sh` file on your desktop, double-clicking it would remove `/path/to/your/folder`

**EDIT AGAIN:**

Sorry, seems that only `chmod` is not enough, please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8409946/how-do-i-make-this-file-sh-executable-via-double-click) post

Comment: how can i create .sh file ?

Comment: `touch my-remove.sh`, or, righ click on the desktop and select create new file? I don't have a mac right now, so this is just guessing:)

Comment: once you created a file, you can edit it with any editor you like, textedit is ok.

Comment: Or if you really don't want to use an editor, use the following command to write in you `sh` file. `echo "rm -rf /your/folder" > my-remove.sh`

Comment: run `touch my-remove.sh` in Terminal to create your `sh` file

Comment: okay i get it.. but for that i have to drag that file into terminal , can i do it by double click ?

Comment: I don't have a mac by my side right now, but I think double-click on the file will work after you use the `chmod` command.